# Ansibile how to check if variable value has three options, ternary operator works only for two options

Tags: ansible

when mountpoint is /dev/backboot is >70% set to 'High' and if < 70% set to 'Normal' and if there is no such mountpoint atall then set to 'not availble'

below example works fine with two options, but i need three options can you suggest

- name: get usage
  command: df -k | grep -i /dev/backboot | awk '{print $5}'
  register: usage

  here output of registered vlaue 'usage.stdout'  is 67% for an example
- name: Set the value
  set_fact:
  mspace: "{{ (usage.stdout | int < 80) | ternary('Normal','High') }}"

Answer (score 0):

Converting `67%` to int will not yield `67`, it will yield `0` because of the `%`, you will need to strip it out of the output.

As for your question, you could just set a condition to set the variable to `not available` if /dev/backboot does not exist:

```
- stat:
    path: /dev/backboot
  register: backboot

- set_fact:
    mspace: 'not available'
  when: backboot.stat.exists != true

- block:
    - command: df -k | grep -i /dev/backboot | awk '{print $5}'
      register: usage

    - set_fact:
        mspace: "{{ (usage.stdout | int < 80) | ternary('Normal','High') }}"
  when: backboot.stat.exists == true
```

Comment: Hi Josh, yes this works, but i have multiple other thing to check similarly where my playbook lines will be more, so to reduce the lines of code and to look neat, was looking some jinja template which can work for three diff options in stdout output

Comment: You could lean on Jinja2 if/elseif/else:

`"{% if 'usage.stdout | int < 80 %}Normal{% elif 'usage.stdout | int >= 80 %}High{% else %}not available{% endif %}"`

Answer (score 0):

With Ansible 2.8 there is a 3rd option for null.   Sort of surprised there is not an error in the setfact when the mountpoint doesn't exist though I've not tried it.

Another option is to add a second setfact and add a when to the existing one and the new one that checks Ansible facts for the mount point - the original would set mspace when it exists and the other when it does not.   Something like this (may change slightly depending on release of ansible and the system that you're running it against).

set_fact:
mspace: "not available"
when: (ansible_devices.backboot is not defined)

and add to priginial setfact

when: (ansible_devices.backboot is defined)

If you have facter available then ansible could use those facts without needing to issue the df command.